# UIScrollView discard default subviews in subview iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am trying to calculate a value from `UIScrollView`'s subviews (subviews added by user). Problem is `UIScrollView` also has its own subviews by default;

```
UIKIT_CLASS_AVAILABLE(2_0) @interface UIScrollView : UIView <NSCoding> {
    ...
    UIImageView* _verticalScrollIndicator;
    UIImageView* _horizontalScrollIndicator;
```

I would like to discard these subviews and calculate my value with the subviews only added by user. How can I detect and discard these above mentioned `UIImageView`s while iterating through scrollView.subviews (`NSArray`)

Comment: Tag all your subviews with a custom tag number... What class are your subviews, how can you make them stand out ? Can you hold an array with references to all your subviews ?

Comment: I am creating a category implementation. That wouldn't be practical

Comment: So what have you considered and ruled out and why. Don't make us guess.

Comment: I haven't figured out what to do :) so haven't tried anything.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to create a subclass of UIScrollView and delete all initial subviews of that UIScrollView, but I would prefer not to

Comment: So if you can subclass the scroll view you can add a custom method for adding subviews and then tag or store each view that's added.

Comment: I would like to see if you can introduce a method which would store each view (both via code and interface builder), maybe their pointers?

Comment: I think UIScrollView shouldn't be used that way. You are supposed to add just one content view to it, not multiple views. If you need multiple subviews, add these subviews to the content view and iterate over `contentView.subviews` instead of `scrollView.subviews`.  Further, if you rely on private implementation details like `_verticalScrollIndicator`, your implementation might break in future versions of iOS.